# best way to loop over Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

SO I have this setting json

```
[{
        "name": "Business",
        "skip": "0",
        "pos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "contact",
        "skip": "1",
        "pos": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "UKSite",
        "skip": "0",
        "pos": "2"
    }
]
```

Then I have my data json

```
[{
    "name": "contact",
    "hideShow": true,
    "data": {
        "con_title": "Sri",
        "con_fName": "Jhon",
        "con_lName": "Snow",
        "emails": ["maheshwar@hsjsk.com", ""],
        "phones": ["8867116216", ""]
    },
    "repeatable": false
}, {
    "name": "UKAddress",
    "hideShow": true,
    "data": {
        "addAddress": [{
            "add_bilding_num": "BUILDING NAME/NUMBER",
            "add_street_name": "STREET",
            "add_town": "TOWN",
            "add_county": "COUNTY",
            "add_pc": "POST CODE",
            "add_type": "TYPE"
        }, {
            "add_bilding_num": "BUILDING NAME/NUMBER",
            "add_street_name": "STREET",
            "add_town": "TOWN",
            "add_county": "COUNTY",
            "add_pc": "POST CODE",
            "add_type": "TYPE"
        }]
    },
    "repeatable": false
}, {
    "name": "Business",
    "hideShow": true,
    "data": {
        "biss_name": "Nano Corporation"
    },
    "repeatable": false
}, {
    "name": "contact",
    "hideShow": true,
    "data": {
        "con_title": "Mr",
        "con_fName": "Roshan",
        "con_lName": "Aslam",
        "emails": ["roshan@throughbit.com"],
        "phones": ["8867116216"]
    },
    "repeatable": true
}, {
    "name": "UKSite",
    "hideShow": true,
    "data": {
        "site_name": "naonocrporation.co.uk",
        "external_rff": "fsfsfs",
        "con_title": "Mr",
        "con_fName": "Kash",
        "con_lName": "Sangh",
        "emails": ["kash@youremail.com"],
        "phones": ["8867116216"],
        "addAddress": [{
            "add_bilding_num": "",
            "add_street_name": "",
            "add_town": "",
            "add_county": "",
            "add_pc": "",
            "add_type": ""
        }],
        "ElecMeter": [{
            "distrib_id": "DISTRIBUTOR ID",
            "pc": "PROFILE CLASS",
            "mtc": "METER TIMESWITCH CODE",
            "llf": "LINE LOSS FACTOR",
            "mpc": "MPAN CORE",
            "eac": "EAC",
            "c_supplr": "CURRENT SUPPLIER",
            "c_date": "CURRENT END DATE",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "distrib_id": "",
            "pc": "",
            "mtc": "",
            "llf": "",
            "mpc": "",
            "eac": "",
            "c_supplr": "",
            "c_date": ""
        }],
        "GasMeter": [{
            "mprn": "MPRN",
            "aq": "AQ",
            "g_c_supplr": "CURRENT SUPPLIER",
            "g_c_date": "CURRENT END DATE"
        }]
    },
    "repeatable": true
}]
```

I have to loop on the data json and using the information from setting json need to create a new Json

for example 
my new json should look like this

```
[{
        "name": "Business",
        "hideShow": true,
        "data": {
            "biss_name": "Nano Corporation"
        },
        "repeatable": false
    },
    {
        "name": "contact",
        "hideShow": true,
        "data": {
            "con_title": "Mr",
            "con_fName": "Roshan",
            "con_lName": "Aslam",
            "emails": [
                "roshan@throughbit.com"
            ],
            "phones": [
                "8867116216"
            ]
        },
        "repeatable": true
    },
    {
        "name": "UKAddress",
        "hideShow": true,
        "data": {
            "addAddress": [{
                    "add_bilding_num": "BUILDING NAME/NUMBER",
                    "add_street_name": "STREET",
                    "add_town": "TOWN",
                    "add_county": "COUNTY",
                    "add_pc": "POST CODE",
                    "add_type": "TYPE"
                },
                {
                    "add_bilding_num": "BUILDING NAME/NUMBER",
                    "add_street_name": "STREET",
                    "add_town": "TOWN",
                    "add_county": "COUNTY",
                    "add_pc": "POST CODE",
                    "add_type": "TYPE"
                }
            ]
        },
        "repeatable": false
    }
]
```

You can Observe , The term `skip:1` which means skip the first one and add rest also the terminology `pos:1` which is telling what should be the position of the object in the new array.

Any help would be great

**Update 1**

I came up with this snippet

`ar finalArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
   var counter = 0;
   for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
      if(b[i].name == a[j].name){
         if(counter < b[i].skip){
            counter++;
            continue;
         }
         finalArray.push(a[j])
      }
   }
}`

Thanks

Comment: wtf are these emails `maheshwar@lovejihad.com` ?!

Comment: FYI you can use jsonlint.com to format your json with proper indentation. you can also use 4space tab have a block-of-code format in your post. I've made an edit to your question

Comment: @Apolo A pretty silly way to get oneself on the radar of the CIA ;)

Comment: @Balázs please check my updated question , i removed the bullshit :P

Comment: @Apolo I am out of danger now , Shall we concentrate on the actualy solution

Comment: @Vikram we could, but your question is not super clear. I would have to guess from your output what your want to do. Could you explain a bit more what your are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with an array of objects and you want to modify each one during the iteration based on conditions, I'd recommend you to use `forEach`

You have docs and examples here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map